# Can the following Huffman tree be extended to include more letters?

Tags: huffman-coding

The following table shows a possible set of Huffman codes to be used for lossless compression of a text consisting only of the eight letters shown:

```
e        t        o        h        l         p         w         z
10       01       111      110      0001      0000      0011      0010
```

The codes will have been chosen by using an algorithm that has as input the frequencies of occurrence of each of the letters in the particular text. The choice of codes can be presented as a Huffman tree. The tree is shown below:

```
                 ()
               /    \
            ()        ()
          /   \      /   \
       ()       t  e       ()   
     /    \              /     \
   ()       ()        h          o
  / \      /  \
p    l    z    w
```

a) Could this tree be extended to include more letters? If not, why not?
b) Can you suggest a modification of the tree to include two more letters?

Comment: As there are no (relative) frequencies of the letters given, it is hard to call this a Huffman tree. Perhaps prefix code would be better.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: There was two previous questions and I have solved them all, I need a clear explanation for these two left ones, or at least a relevant clue.